# Как узнать размер массива, возвращённого функцией?

Tags: c, массивы

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* create_arr(int number1, int number2, int number3) {
    int* arr = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);
    arr[0] = number1;
    arr[1] = number2;
    arr[2] = number3;
    return arr;
}

int main(void) {
    int* arr = create_arr(2, 3, 4);
    printf("%lu\n", sizeof(arr));
}
```

`printf` в `main` выводит `4`. Логично, потому что именно столько байт в моей системе занимает указатель. Но что, если я хочу вывести все значения полученного массива? Как мне найти конец массива?

В приведённом примере я, конечно, знаю, что функция `create_arr` создаёт массив из 3ёх значений, но я пытаюсь сделать функцию-фильтр для массивов, которая возвращает массив подходящих значений. Размер такого массива будет зависеть от исходного, и я не буду знать, каким он будет. Что тогда делать? Как вывести результат?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть как минимум два варианта:

1. Вернуть размер в отдельной переменной (передать указатель в функцию)

   ```
   int* f(size_t* size) { 
     // ... 
     *size = <нужное число элементов>;
   }
   ```
2. Использовать некое служебное значение в качестве конечного элемента. Если известно, что массив может содержать только числа из определённого диапазона, например, только положительные, то первое отрицательное число может быть маркером конца массива. Такой подход используется для сишных строк - указатель на `char` (массив), в последний элемент которого записан нулевой символ `\0`. Это удобно, что не нужна дополнительная именованная переменная, но зато приходится тратить O(N) времени на поиск длины строки (массива). Если такого числа придумать нельзя (все числа являются валидными для массива), то стоит использовать отдельную переменную (см.п.1).

Какого-то иного переносимого способа узнать на основании указателя на динамическую память сколько байт (и следовательно, элементов) было выделено не существует.

Comment: Если тип данных в массиве позволяет,  то можно вместо отдельной переменной использовать первый элемент массива для возврата его размера

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов ага. Или так. Pascal way.